# Retrieving deep nested values looping through a HTML page using HTMLAgilityPack C#

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to use the HTMLAgilityPack to retrieve various specific values from a web page. The web page is always the same an the data I want to scrape from it is always in the same place (same divs/classes/attributes etc).

I've tried to loop through and get the values, but I always mess up somewhere. I'd provide some code to help but honestly I've tried 5 times and each time I don't get results close to what I want to - I'm well and truly in a pickle.

I have written the main chunk of HTML:

```
<div id ="markers">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="span2 filter-pane   ">
         <div class="teaser teaser-small">
            <h1 class="teaser-title">
            <a href="#map" data-lat="Value1" data-lng="Value2" data-name="Value3">...</a>
         </div>
         <p> Value4 </p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="span2 filter-pane   ">
   </div>
   <div class="span2 filter-pane   ">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
</div>
```

Basically the values (1-4) are the values I want to extract from the data.

The `<div id="markers">` is ONE div on the page, all the information I need is in this div.

There are multiple `<div class="row">` divs, I need to loop through all of these.

Inside each of these divs, there are three or less `<div class="span2 filter-pane   ">` divs. I need to loop through these 3 divs also.

My data is inside here - Value3 is here in the `<p>...</p>`. And the other values can be found within the `<h1 class="teaser-title">` node, where they are attributes in an `<a>` element.

I hope somebody can provide me with a solution, or at least some good guidance to accessing all pieces of data I want. I've tried various things but I don't get the results I want.

Thanks.

Comment: You should provide the code you attempted and explain how it doesn't work. Otherwise it just seems (even if it wasn't your intention) like you want us to write your code for you. That's not what we're here for.

Comment: Keep in mind that this chunk of HTML is not properly formatted, according to your instructions at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some hints for you. So first you need to get `div#markers` because you mentioned that it contains all your info you need.

```
string mainURL = your url;
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(mainURL);
var markerDiv = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").FirstOrDefault(n => n.Id.Equal("markers');
//Check if marketDiv is null or not
//Same idea, get list of row divs
var rows = marketDiv.Descendants("div").HasClass("row") //I will provide .HasClass function or you can write your own, it's simple;
//Iterate throw your rows object
//for each row object
var aElement = row.Descendants("a").FirstOrDefault()//you can have more criteria here if it has more than 1 a element
aElement.GetAttributeValue("data-lat", "") //will return Value1 here, do the same thing for other attributes and p.
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you so much, the thing I was really missing out of my own knowledge is the .Descendants method - your code will help me implement what I want if I apply it to my case, thank you :)